# Cosmos emulator on Docker for Linux - Can python program interact with it?

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, emulation

I have successfully installed a Cosmos emulator with Docker on Linux following the instruction in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21

I just wonder for Cosmos emulator installed on Windows environment, we could simply create a Cosmos client by using the following Python code running locally:

```
from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey

endpoint = "https://localhost:8081"

key = 'C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=='

client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)
```

However, applying the same Python code in Linux, I would receive the following errors:

```
ServiceRequestError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)
```

Is that the Linux Cosmos emulator only supports SQL API, but not Python code? Or I should amend the coding when the emulator is installed in Linux?

Comment: I could connect remotely using pyDocumentDB document client.  However I cannot create database and container that way ... can I connect with CosmosClient?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to export the emulator certificate to successfully use the emulator endpoint in different languages.

Please follow the steps from this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-export-ssl-certificates#export-emulator-certificate) to export the Azure Cosmos DB TLS /SSL certificate.